# Missing: after property list

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This code is giving me this error: `missing : after property list` where error comment is.

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>").jPlayer({
     ready: function () {
          $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
               <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
          });
     },
     $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { //ERROR HERE
          $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
     },
     solution:"flash,html",
     swfPath: "jquery",
     supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
});
```

I want to know how to fix this error and am I implementing the `pauseOthers` function correctly by looking at this documentation:  [DOCUMENTATION](http://www.jplayer.org/latest/developer-guide/#jPlayer-pauseOthers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're putting this call:

```
$(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { //ERROR HERE
  $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
}
```

Smack in the middle of declaring an object literal:

```
{
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
      });
    },
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
}
```

which is simply invalid JavaScript syntax. Perhaps you meant to put the `.bind()` call inside of the `ready` callback?

```
 $("#jquery_jplayer_1-<?php echo $key.'-'.$j; ?>").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
      $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
        <?php echo $info['extension'];?>: "<?php echo "AudioFiles/".$a; ?>"
      });
      $(this).bind($.jPlayer.event.play, function() { 
          $(this).jPlayer("pauseOthers");
        });
    },
    solution:"flash,html",
    swfPath: "jquery",
    supplied: "<?php echo $info['extension'];?>"
});
```

Comment: Can I ask something if you don't mind, have you ever used jplayer before? I want to implement this http://www.jplayer.org/latest/demo-03/ but do not know how to do this. At the moment if I have multiple jplayer audio players, If I click on one, it plays the audio in all players, rather than its own player. That is what I am trying to achieve but struggling

Comment: No, I haven't used jPlayer. Open a new question, and next time don't bother showing the PHP – please show the generated JavaScript, since that's what the browser sees.